# How does Voxel grid works?

Tags: ros, object-detection, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How does voxel grid implementation works? I need more details, cant seems to visualize it.

Is there any other object avoidance method for mobile based? Thanks in advance :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236001/how-does-voxel-grid-works?/) by [Donovan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27064/donovan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

More details than what? It's a 3D grid: A collection of aligned boxes: [voxel grid http://developer94.openinventor.com/sites/default/files/imported/usersguide/images/VVOverview1.png](http://developer94.openinventor.com/sites/default/files/imported/usersguide/images/VVOverview1.png).

It can be "implemented" using a 3D array in memory, but for voxel maps one usually uses an octree.

If you want to know more about voxel mapping see the page of the [octomap library](https://octomap.github.io/), where you will also find visualizations of voxel grids/maps.

You can also use meshes to query the closest point between two meshes (one is your robot model, the other part of the environment). But as far as I know, performance-wise these are limited to low amounts of polygons, i.e., not well suitable for meshes generated from sensor data.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Donovan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27064/donovan/) on 2016-06-04**:
How does it know if the cell is free, occupied and unknown space? BTW I'm new to ros. Thanks for the reply! Appreciate it :D

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-06**:
Raycasting. For more information about voxel mapping I recommend [this publication](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ehornunga/pub/hornung13auro.pdf).